# Reactjs using Context Api with nested route not sharing a state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-context

I am implement an application with parent route with nested routes that wrapper with a `context Api` to share state between all components.

When changing the state in first route component and navigate to the second one the state return the initial values.

My code so far:

Main route:

```
<GuardedRoute path="/onboarding" component={Onbaording} />
```

Nested routes wrapper with context api:

```
  export function Onbaording(props:any) {
  const { path} = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <OnboardingStore>
      <MainLayout>
        <Switch>
        <Route path={`${path}/select-service`} component={ServiceSelectionPage} exact  />
          <Route path={`${path}/basic-info`} component={TutorBasicInfo} exact/>
          <Route path={`${path}/experience`} component={TutorExperience} exact/>
          <Route path={`${path}/how-we-work`} component={TutorHowIntoWorks} />
          <Route path={`${path}/training-teaching-types`} component={TrainingTeachingTypes} exact/>
          <Route path={`${path}/subjects`} component={Subjects} exact/>
          <Route path={`${path}/terms-and-conditions`} component={TermisAndConditions} exact/>
          <Redirect to={`${path}/select-service`}/>
        </Switch>
      </MainLayout>
     </OnboardingStore>
  );
}
```

Gaured Route:

```
 const [isLoading,setIsLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(true);
const [authenticatedUser,setAuthenticatedUser] = React.useState<any>(null);
React.useEffect(()=>{
         checkAuthState();
},[])
async function checkAuthState() {
    try {
     Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then((user)=>{
        setAuthenticatedUser(new User(user));
         setIsLoading(false);
     }).catch(error=>{
        setAuthenticatedUser(null)
        setIsLoading(false);
     })
    } catch (err) {
        setAuthenticatedUser(null)
    }
  }
return (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        component={(props:any) => (
            isLoading ? ' Loading... ' : 
            (
            authenticatedUser?
           <Component {...props} />
            :
                <Redirect to={'/sign-in'} />
            )
        )}
    />
)
```

Context Api Code:

```
   const OnboardingStore = (props: any) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const router: any = useRouter();
  const params = useParams();
  const http = HttpService.instance;
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const sections = ['basicInfo','experience','howIntoWorks','trainingAndTeachingTypes','subjects'];

  React.useEffect(()=>{
   console.log('')
  },[])
  const setOnBoardingSection = (section: string) => {
    dispatch(actions.setOnboardingSection(section));
    calcProgressBar();
  };
  const updateServicesInState = (services: IOnboardingServices) => {
    dispatch(actions.updateOnboardingServices(services));
  };
  const setOnBoardingSectionStateOnNavigation = (section: string,status:string) => {
    if(state[section].state==='complete' || state[section].state==='skipped')return;
      dispatch(actions.setOnBoardingSectionStateOnNavigation(section,status));
  };
  const setOnBoardingSectionStateOnAction = (section: string,status:string) => {
      dispatch(actions.setOnBoardingSectionStateOnNavigation(section,status));
  };
 const calcProgressBar  = ()=>{
   let percentageValue = 0;
   sections.forEach((section:any)=>{
      percentageValue = state[section].state==='complete' || state[section].state==='skipped' ? percentageValue+20 : percentageValue;
   })
   dispatch(actions.setOnBoardingProgressBarValue(percentageValue));

 }
  const value = {
    state,
    setOnBoardingSection,
    updateServicesInState,
    setOnBoardingSectionStateOnNavigation,
    calcProgressBar,
    setOnBoardingSectionStateOnAction
  };

  return (
    <OnboardingContext.Provider value={value}>
      {props.children}
    </OnboardingContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Component consume state:

```
  export function TutorBasicInfo() {
      const history = useHistory();
      const {
        state,
        setOnBoardingSectionStateOnNavigation,
        setOnBoardingSection,
        setOnBoardingSectionStateOnAction,
      } = React.useContext<any>(OnboardingContext);
....
```

Reducer code:

```
const reducer = (state: any, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionsTypes.SET_ONBOARDING_SECTION:
      return {
        ...state,
        section:action.payload.value,
      }
    case actionsTypes.UPDATE_ONBOARDING_SECTION:
      return {
        ...state,
         services:{...state.services,serviceIds:action.payload.value.services.serviceIds},
      };

    case actionsTypes.SET_ONBOARDING_SECTION_STATE:
      state[action.payload.section] = {...state[action.payload.section],state:action.payload.status}
      return {
        ...state,
      };
      case actionsTypes.SET_ONBOARDING_PROGRESS_BAR_VALUE:
      return {
        ...state,
        progressPercentage:action.payload.value
      };
    default:
      return {...state};
  }
};
```

It seems that the issue occurs because of the navigation between routes so the whole wrapper components re-rendered.

any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify what "state return the initial values" means? What is "the first route component", the "second route component", and what state is being updated?

Comment: I am changing the state in the first nested route component so I want to handle the updated state in the second route when I navigate to it but the state not changing return its initial values sound of it is reinstantiate.

Comment: Sorry, have you included all the relevant code in your question? What state are you referring to being updated? Your question/issue is unclear.

Comment: I updated my question I added the context api code

Comment: And can you also share with us how any consuming components are trying to update the state, and the `reducer` function that is actually doing the update?

Comment: Check question updates

Comment: Where and how are you queueing the state updates and navigation? I suspect the navigation is occurring *before* the state has actually been updated since React updates state asynchronously.